# insert values to database with hibernate

Tags: sql, hibernate

```
    SessionFactory factory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session session = factory.openSession();
    session.getTransaction();
    gorev.setAciklama(gorev.getAciklama());
    gorev.setTarih(gorev.getTarih());
    gorev.setDurum(gorev.getDurum());
    SQLQuery kuid = session.createSQLQuery("insert into gorev (kullaniciid,aciklama,tarih,durum) VALUES ('"+kullanici.getId()+"','" + gorev.getAciklama() + "','" + gorev.getTarih() +"','" + gorev.getDurum()+ "','");
    //List<Kullanici> list = kuid.list();
    //session.save(kuid.uniqueResult());

    session.save(kuid);

    session.beginTransaction();
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
```

Why i can not add that values on database.

I can add use  /session.save(gorev)\
except id. kullaniciid is my foreign key, reference table is kullanici and referenced fields is id.

Comment: There is nothing JSF related in this question. So the tag is not relevant here. If you think there is something JSF related in your problem, make a [mcve] and 'prove' jsf is the cause of your problem. But then it is with 99.9% certainty not sql, hibernate or jpa related.

Comment: There is nothing JPA related in this question. Do you know which API you are using?!

Answer (score 0):

here u put the same object !! non ??

```
  gorev.setAciklama(gorev.getAciklama());
gorev.setTarih(gorev.getTarih());
gorev.setDurum(gorev.getDurum());
```

if gorev.aciklama is null it will still

Comment: what do you mean dude "same object" it is my first jpa project

Answer (score 0):

1. Try kuid.executeUpdate();
   session.save is for persistent entities
2. Begin transactions should be before saving. It doesn't make sense to give after saving.

Comment: session is not have executeUpdate(); method.how can i use kuid.executeUpdate(); or where ?

Comment: and kuid.executeUpdate(); is not working it is same.

Comment: Is it giving any exception? execute update should work. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html#executeUpdate()

Comment: i get this exception sir   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: VALUES near line 1, column 54 [insert into gorev (kullaniciid,aciklama,tarih,durum) VALUES ('null','acklama','11.2.2016','durum')]

Comment: Is there an extra comma in your query?